# Jquery - TimeOut Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to run the following jQuery Code.

```
$('body.player').find('.tab').click(function(){
      $('.playerLoaders').addClass('loading');

      setTimeout(function() {
            if( !$(this).hasClass('active') ){
                 $('.playerLoaders').removeClass('loading');
                 $('.tab-content[data-tab="' + $(this).attr('data-tab') + '"]').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
                 $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
            }
            return false;
      },5000);
});
```

But something is not working quite right.
The div-tag "playerLoaders" is working perfectly, but the tab-content-div is not removing the active class, and adding it to the active tab.

If I delete the TimeOut-function, the tabs are working just fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you waiting 5 seconds to see if things change? `.playLoaders` will change on the click... everything else waits 5 seconds, then runs *IF* it doesn't have the `.active` class.

Comment: try placing the timeout function after the if statement

Comment: just what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: 'this' is referencing the setTimeout context, and not the outer function context. You should do var self = this; and use self inside the setTimeout function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the setTimeout function, 'this' is referencing the setTimeout context, and not the outer function context. You should get a reference to the outer function context. Consider this:

```
$('body.player').find('.tab').click(function(){
      var self = this;
      $('.playerLoaders').addClass('loading');

      setTimeout(function() {
            if( !$(self).hasClass('active') ){
                 $('.playerLoaders').removeClass('loading');
                 $('.tab-content[data-tab="' + $(self).attr('data-tab') + '"]').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
                 $(self).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
            }
            return false;
      },5000);
});
```

If you want to keep using 'this' inside the setTimeout function, you can also bind it like this:

```
setTimeout((function() {
            if( !$(this).hasClass('active') ){
                 $('.playerLoaders').removeClass('loading');
                 $('.tab-content[data-tab="' + $(this).attr('data-tab') + '"]').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
                 $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
            }
            return false;
}).bind(this),5000);
```

Comment: Hi carlosdubusm

Thank you for the input. The problem is, that know when I click, the .playerLoaders gets the loading class added, but nothing else happens.

The TimeOut function, doesn't get activated?

Comment: Did you try using 'self' instead of 'this'? Can you post a jsfiddle with the issue?

Comment: Hi again @carlosdubusm

It was actually working, I had a "." where there shouldn't be one - sorry for that!